# Round 4 numbers after point for float value

Tags: jquery

I have a float numbers like : 0.24405750549007688

I would like to convert it to -> 0.2441

How can i do it with jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0.24405750549007688.toFixed(4)
"0.2441" <-- string

parseFloat(0.24405750549007688.toFixed(4))
0.2441 <-- number
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using bellow

```
(6.688689).toFixed(); // equal to 7
(6.688689).toFixed(1); // equal to 6.7
(6.688689).toFixed(2); // equal to 6.69
```

Answer (score 0):

`var myFourDigit = (0.24405750549007688).toFixed(4) // will output 0.2440`

Answer (score 0):

not efficient but it will do the trick:

```
var n=0.24405750549007688
n*=10000;
n=Math.round(n)/10000;
console.log(n);
```